# Android database handler with imageview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, imageview, android-context

I have created an activity that uses a canvas on which I can draw.

Within the activity, I need to retrieve data from a table that I have created elsewhere.

In other activities, I have used the database handler below and it works fine.

In this it does not, I think because I have extended imageview (required for the canvas) rather than extending Activity.

Thank you in advance for any help....

Here is my code:

```
public class examplecanvas extends ImageView {

float xPos, yPos;
private PointF point;
private Paint paint = new Paint();

public examplecanvas(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public examplecanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public examplecanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (point != null) {
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 100, paint);
        canvas.save();
    }
}


public void getmydata() {

    String parenta = "parent"

    myDBhandler1 dbHandler;
    dbHandler = new myDBhandler1(examplecanvas.this, null, null, 1); <<<<HERE IS THE ERROR

}
}
```

...and this is the error I get:

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database handler requires a context, so you could pass

```
new myDbHandler1(getContext(), ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

"examplecanvas.this" does not have context like you want to provide to the DBHandler constructor. You should pass Context in your getmydata() function as a parameter (Then use YourActivity.this or getActivity() when you call this method, depends on Activity or Fragemnt). Or simply use the Context received in your extended ImageView constructors.